# Materialize + Angular Search and Filter Responsive Table with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, materialize

`StuffieStephie` has created a very nice [Pen](https://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/BzmxXd?limit=all&page=17&q=table) that has everything I need.

However even if I start using newer libraries I cannot get the email all filtered users to work - the outlook window pops up but the To list is empty

```
<div id="email-list" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="row">   <b ng-repeat="d in names | filter:filters">{{d.email}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</b></div>
    </div>
</div>
<a ng-href="mailto:{{d.email}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}" class="waves-effect waves-light btn margin-bottom-1em"><i class="material-icons left">email</i>Email All {{selected.field}} Volunteers ({{(names | filter:filters).length}})</a>
<a href="#email-list" class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light btn margin-bottom-1em">View List of Email Addresses ({{(names | filter:filters).length}})</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

After `$scope.names` is defined in the code, add this: (line 363)

```
$scope.emails = $scope.names.map(n => n.email).join(",");
```

Go to line 38, and change the function to this:

```
$scope.hasChanged = function() {
  $scope.filters = $scope.selected.field;
  var emails = $scope.names;
  if ($scope.filters) emails = emails.filter(n => n.status == $scope.filters);
  $scope.emails = emails.map(n => n.email).join(",");
}
```

In the email link part, use

```
ng-href="mailto:?bcc={{emails}}"
```

Comment: Made the changes even directly on the pen itself and it still pops up blank. Tried Cc, To but no joy.

Comment: Thank you. It seems Internet Explorer (tried with 9 10 and 11) doesn't like the => symbol in: $scope.hasChanged = function() {
  $scope.filters = $scope.selected.field;
  var emails = $scope.names;
  if ($scope.filters) emails = emails.filter(n => n.status == $scope.filters);
  $scope.emails = emails.map(n => n.email).join(",");
}

Comment: That's an arrow function, just replace it with the old style. `emails.filter(function (n) { return n.status == $scope.filters; })';` and `$scope.emails = emails.map(function (n) { return n.email; }).join(",");`

Comment: Thank you. Tried that and it did display properly on IE, however the drop down selection stopped filtering the results. Lost that functionality on all browsers.